# Why absolute-path is not working in my project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, relative-path, absolute-path

the hierarchy of my files looks something like:

```
BACKEND(COMPLETE)
->Routers
   ->userrouter.js
->login.html
```

I wanted the access of my login.html file in userrouter.js for which I copied the Path(absolute) of the login.html file.

But I am getting this error:

path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile()

My Code:

```
function loginUser(req,res)
{
res.sendFile('C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\backend(complete)\login.html');
res.end();
}
```

Comment: C:\Users\  backslash in Javascript is an escape sequence, you need to do C:\\Users\\..   But I believe node will also automatically convert forward slashes for you so, C:/users/ will likely work too.

Comment: @Keith I replaced all backslashes with  forwardslashes,but it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying `C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\backend(complete)\login.html` to `C:/\Users/\ASUS/\Desktop/\backend(complete)/\login.html`

Try using path (path.join) npm package which Node provides out of the box to avoid this confusion irrespective of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Npm package `path` and use `path.join(["yourpath", "here")` for cross system compatibility. Note that every part between slashes needs to be its own entry in the array.